# Coverage.py does not include all files and folder specified

Tags: python, flask, coverage.py

Line below is the part of my `manage.py` code

```
cov = coverage.Coverage(branch=True,
                            include="app/*"
```

But when i run test with coverage i received coverage for only two files inside app/

My app directory has the following files and folder

[image]

Results I get after running coverage

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Flask, but often the problem with web apps is that they spawn subprocesses to do the actual work.

Comment: So  what are you suggesting @NedBatchelder